# Build Glibc for android ndk in eclipse

Tags: android-ndk, glibc

I have a C program (which uses glibc) that I wish to run on android. I installed android ndk and have setup the basic things. How should I link glibc library to my android project in eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> How should I link glibc library to my android project in eclipse?

Android doesn't use GLIBC (it uses [Bionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)) instead).

So your first step would be "port GLIBC to work on Android". Your question suggests that you may not be up to that task, and a better approach may be to make your program compatible with Bionic (i.e. to not use any glibc-specific extensions) instead.